# Sencha Ext Panel Fill Browser

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following application and it fills the screen no problem horizontally. I would like it to fill out vertically as well.

```
var missionsPanel = new Ext.panel.Panel
        (
            {
                title: 'Active Missions', width: '35%', renderTo: Ext.getBody(), layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch', padding: 5}
            }
        );

        resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'ISR Toolkit v3.0',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: { type: 'hbox', align: 'fit', padding: 5 },
            items: 
            [ missionsPanel, { xtype: 'splitter' },
                { title: 'Person Details', bodyPadding: 5, flex: 2,
                        items: 
                        [
                            { itemId: 'txtName', fieldLabel: 'Name:', xtype: 'textfield'}, 
                            { itemId: 'txtAge', fieldLabel: 'Age', xtype: 'textfield'},
                            { itemId: 'btnShow', xtype: 'button', height: '60', width: 125, align: 'right', text: 'Show Data', handler: createNewMissionWindow }
                        ] 
                }       
            ]
        });
```

I am sure it's something small I a missing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a [Viewport](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport) with a `fit` layout, and the only `item` being your panel (removing the `renderTo` configs, as well as any height/width).